# How to handle file access in a reactive environment

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I'm refactoring some blocking code to reactive (using Reactor). I think most of the methods in the `java.nio.file.Files` class are blocking.

Is it right if I replace a method like:

```
public boolean exists() {
    return Files.exists(path);
}
```

with:

```
public Mono<Boolean> exists() {
    return Mono.fromSupplier(() -> Files.exists(path));
}
```

I think it's necessary, especially when cheap HDDs are used.

Or does a library exists in Reactor for this kind of file manipulation?

Comment: That seems to be the general approach I've seen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally yes, but your code misses one important part: assigning a scheduler.

It does not really matter whether some call is decorated by wrapping it into a `Mono`. What matters is on what Scheduler (thread) that code runs. Your code misses a `.subscribeOn(boundedElastic())` call.

(`Schedulers.boundedElastic()` is [a good choice](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#schedulers) for work that involves blocking I/O).

Alternatively, a thread running the code can be changed with a `.publishOn()` call. E.g. if you deal with an existing `Flux<Path>` (instead of a simple `Path` value as is in your case), you can use a `.publishOn()` to switch threads and a simple `map()` to call the blocking method. For example:

```
Mono.just(path).publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic()).map(Files::exists)
```

also achieves the goal, though is more ugly.